# How to delete outputted index.js after Webpack finishes?

Tags: webpack, html-webpack-plugin

I am using HtmlWebpackInlineSourcePlugin with HtmlWebpackPlugin to inline all js and css files in the bundled html file. I want to delete these js and css files from the output directory after generating the html file as they are not needed anymore. Is there an option or plugin to do this?

I am also using CleanWebpackPlugin but it is not suitable for the job.

Thank you!

Comment: Why isn't CleanWebpackPlugin suitable ? I use it to do specifically what you're asking.

Comment: Because it deletes the files before Webpack generates the output index.js and I need to delete this output file after it has been generated because I do not need it anymore after inlining it into the index.html file. Any clue how to do it with CleanWebpackPlugin?

Comment: Have you tried switching the plugin's position in the plugins list? Is it the last item in the array?

Comment: I tried putting it last but no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [webpack-shell-plugin](https://github.com/1337programming/webpack-shell-plugin)

install through npm:

```
npm install --save-dev webpack-shell-plugin
```

require in webpack.config.js

```
const WebpackShellPlugin = require('webpack-shell-plugin');
```

add to plugins array:

```
plugins: [
    new WebpackShellPlugin({onBuildEnd:['rm dist/*.js']})
]
```

Comment: This works I think, however I should have added in the question that I am looking for a configurable plugin not command lines if possible?